# Cannot exit bash script correctly

Tags: bash, exit, zenity

I have a made a script on bash.

```
#!/bin/bash

zen(){
mark=$(zenity --scale \
    --text 'FREQUENCY' \
    --value=$la \
    --min-value=0\
    --max-value=5000 \
    --step=1)
}
la=500

echo "Script for shim. Regulary frequency"
zen
while [ true ] 
do

case $? in

    0) echo $mark
       la=$mark
       #zenity --notification --window-icon="info" --text="Thank you!" --timeout=1
       zen
    ;;
    1) 
       # exit 1
       # sl -e || break
       # break
       # return 1       
    ;;
esac 
done
echo "thanks for using!"
```

It works okay, excluding exit point. # stands before options I have tried, and every one of them does not allow to exit this script correctly and instead of "thanks for using!" or just nothing I am getting in terminal:

```
This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

^XThis option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

This option is not available. Please see --help for all possible usages.

.........................................
```

It looks like it is problem with zenity, when I am trying to exit the script. I looked this error up and only sound thought was to upgrade zenity, which I have done but it has given me nothing new...

So how can I solve it and break this script correctly..?

My OS is Ubuntu Server 16.04

**EDIT**

By my script I would like to achieve repeating question from zenity till the moment when user clicks 'cancel'

Comment: This looks terrible. The `while [ true ] ` does work as expected but probably not for the reason you assume. The `case $? in` refers to the `[ true ] ` and not to the `zen`. And obviously your `zenity` call is wrong.

Comment: Thanks! It is terrible probably, I am not so sophisticated in bash-programming.. Could you change my script to the correct one? By my script I would like to achieve repeating question from zenity till the moment when user clicks 'cancel'

Comment: I can correct the structure but I need to know what the *working* `zenity` call looks like.

Comment: Call zenity-scale needs for collecting value from scale permanently till user decides to quit and close the window. In working mode script must collect value from zenity-scale and pull them into termnial when user clicks ''Ok'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$?` is the exit status of the last command that was run. In your case, that's of the `[` command (which you use to test whether the `true` string is non-empty as a condition of your `while` loop).

You almost never need to use `$?` explicitly. Just do

```
la=500
while
  mark=$(zenity --scale \
      --text 'FREQUENCY' \
      --value="$la" \
      --min-value=0 \
      --max-value=5000 \
      --step=1)
do
  echo "$mark"
  la=$mark
done
```

Or simply:

```
mark=500
while
  mark=$(zenity --scale \
      --text 'FREQUENCY' \
      --value="$mark" \
      --min-value=0 \
      --max-value=5000 \
      --step=1)
do
  echo "$mark"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a missing space before the backslash in your `zenity` call which may cause the error:

```
zen(){
mark=$(zenity --scale \
    --text FREQUENCY \
    --value=$la \
    --min-value=0 \
    --max-value=5000 \
    --step=1)
}

la=500

echo "Script for shim. Regulary frequency"
zen
zen_ec=$?
while true
do

    case $zen_ec in

        0) echo $mark
           la=$mark
           #zenity --notification --window-icon="info" --text="Thank you!" --timeout=1
           zen
        ;;

[...]
```

Comment: Since it's `--min-value=0\<newline>    --max-value=5000`, it should be OK, the `\<newline>` is removed but that's still `--min-value=0    --max-value=5000` so both options are separated (because of the spaces at the start of the `--max-value`. There are issues with unquoted variables though, and the fact that `$?` that the OP is checking is the exit status of the `[` command, not the `zen` function.

Comment: This code is giving the same result...